# How can I filter each category in a column of a CSV file and save all of them into new files using python?

Tags: python, csv, file, filter, save

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghR73.png)

So here is a sample. What I want to do is to filter the third column. Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1psf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ1Se.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq6Nn.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqlu7.png)
and save each of them into a new file. What can I do? (save as new files instead of changing the original file)

Comment: Please share minimal reproducible example with input/output https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.
Not as image.

Comment: What is the exact criteria for filtering?